# Python - 100 coin tosses

Tags: python

i need to write code that will simulate 100 coin tosses and efter that show us how many tails and heads we drop. What am i doing wrong?

```
import random

orzel = 0
reszka = 0
suma = orzel + reszka
while suma != 100:
    rzut = random.randint(1,6)
    if rzut == 1:
        orzel +=1
    if rzut == 2:
        reszka +=1

print(orzel, "i", reszka)
input("koniec")
```

Comment: If you're supposed to be simulating coin tosses, why are you rolling a die?

Comment: rand(1,6) is wrong because a coin has only 2 sites. Also you don't changing `suma` in the loop. So you get an infinite loop.

Comment: update `suma` in the while loop. Or better, don't use it at all, just test `orzel + reszka != 100` in the while condition.

Comment: @user2357112 if the die is equally likely to land on `1` as `2`, and you ignore all other outcomes and reroll, is it really any different?

Comment: Simpler: `count_heads = numpy.random.binomial(100, 0.5)`

Answer (score 2):

You can fix your code by using `random.randint(1,2)` and moving `suma = orzel + reszka` inside the loop, but it's better to use a bit more pythonic approach like this:

```
from random import choice
outcome = {'orzel':0, 'reszka':0}
for i in range(100):
    outcome[choice(['orzel','reszka'])] += 1
print(outcome)
```

Comment: Very pythonic indeed